# How too allow a client on a server to send multiple messages? JAVA

Tags: java, loops, server, client, chat

I've been making a chat room where multiple clients can connect and talk together on the same server. **The only problem I'm having is getting each client to send more than one message.** I've been trying different ways of looping the method to do so but I'm having some issues.
Any help would be appreciated :) thank you.
**HERE'S THE CODE:**

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner clientInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        Socket SOCK = new Socket("localhost", 14001);
        System.out.println("Client started!");

        //Streams
        while(true){
        OutputStream OUT = SOCK.getOutputStream(); //writing data to a destination
        PrintWriter WRITE = new PrintWriter(OUT); // PrintWriter prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream

        InputStream in = SOCK.getInputStream(); //reads data from a source
        BufferedReader READ = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //---------------------------------
        System.out.print("My input: ");
        String atServer =  clientInput.nextLine();

        WRITE.write(atServer + "\n");
        WRITE.flush();  //flushes the stream

        String stream = null;

        while((stream = READ.readLine()) != null){  //if stream is not empty
            System.out.println("Client said: " + stream);
        }

        READ.close();
        WRITE.close();
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I've tried using a while loop to continuously ask for an input but doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making it out of the READ.readLine() while loop? Perhaps you're never getting an end of input character and thats never terminating. Also, you're closing both your READ and WRITE at the end of the while loop, and then expect them to be open on the next iteration. Move those and the close statements to the same layer as the Socket. 
With that, every time you send something, your client is expecting something in response from the server. If you don't want them to be dependent on each other, I recommend moving the receive logic to its own thread in a while(true) loop.